# Prepend on IE 8 has a break and IE 9 does not

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

The desired behavior is not have a break

**JS**
    $('button:contains("Add")').prepend(' ');

**IE 9**

[image]

**IE 8**

[image]

**CSS**

```
button {
  color: #fff;

  font-family: "TWC Round Medium",Arial,Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 9px 13px;
  margin-right : 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  background-size: 100%;

  ...

  /* background image stuff removed */
}
```

How do I make these have the same behavior

Comment: We need to see your css.  But, it appears that your button is possibly too narrow, or your css isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: Prepend just inserts into the DOM. The layout is the same as if you'd written the HTML directly.

Comment: @Barmar is correct, although IE sometimes does the layout around spaces in an unusual way. Perhaps you should try to use border/padding/margin for that spacing instead of a text space.